# Store string in char array in C -- What am I doing incorrectly?

Tags: c, arrays, posix

I am retrieving a string from getline() as follows:

```
length = getline(&line, &linecap, stdin);
```

This string contains spaces.

I am then inserting this line in an array:

```
char *history[10];
history[0]=line;
```

I then print the content of this entry from the array:

```
printf("\nHISTORY[%d] = %s", 0, (history[0]));
```

The issue is that only the first word gets print to the screen. It appears like only the first word actually gets stored in the array.

If for example line = "This is such a great line". I then insert this line in the history array, but only the word "This" gets printed from my printf.

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: How large is linecap?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You can't do this:  `history[0]=line;`  That's not valid in C or, more correctly, it's valid but it is extremely unlikely that this is what you meant to do.  Read the manage for `strcpy`, `strncpy`, `sprintf`, `snprintf`...

Comment: `getline` is not standard C.

Comment: you'll need to make sure you reset `line = NULL` before calling getline again, otherwise it will re-use the same buffer

Comment: @olaf: It's in the Posix standard. Are you implying that one cannot use Posix interfaces in a C question? If so, what would you propose that potential questioners with questions about Posix interfaces do?

Comment: @programmedChem: Why do so many people put newlines at the *beginning* of their output lines instead of at the end? It's practically never what you want, particularly since stdout tends to be *line*-buffered which means that it doesn't output a line until it sees the terminating newline character.

Comment: @rici: No, you cannot! Because POSIX is not C and most C implementations do not support POSIX (most are not even hosted implementations actually). But you very well can add the POSIX tag to a question!

Comment: @Olaf: I don't believe that the C tag implies that the question needs to be applicable to every C implementation in the world. But I added the tag.

Comment: @rici: Please read the info page! It is clearly about **standard C**. Exactly **not** to be about "every C implementation in the world"!

Comment: @Olaf It's OK for C programs to call functions from various libraries, few real world programs do otherwise

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You cannot write `history[0] = line`. You need to use `strcpy`:

```
strcpy(history[0], line)
```

The first argument is the destination, and the second argument is the source. However, you did not allocate space for any of the elements in `history`. They are just pointers that do not point at valid areas. You can solve this by

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    history[i] = malloc(strlen(line) + 1);
```

Now you can copy into `history[i]`.

And when you are done, you must free the memory

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    free(history[i]);
```

But the problem with `strcpy`, is that it if there is not enough space in the destination, a buffer overflow occurs. To solve this, rewrite `strcpy` to accept a length.

```
void mystrcpy(char *dest, char *src, size_t n)
{
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < n && *dest++ = *src++; ++i)
        ;
    dest[i] = 0;
}
```

The above function only copies the first `n` characters from `src` to `dest`. It is an improvement.

Comment: If using this approach, the `malloc` size should be `strlen(line)+1`, not `16`

Comment: Do not make your own strcpy-like functions. `mystrcpy` fails to null-terminate the buffer, which certainly is not what OP will want

Comment: Not sure I understand this answer. What is intrinsically wrong with storing the `line` pointer into an array? Why does a copy need to be made? Certainly it can be done incorrectly (e.g. if `line` is reused for multiple input lines and stored into different array entries). But we cannot jump to that conclusion without seeing the rest of the OP's code so any recommendation to use `strcpy` would appear premature at best.

Comment: `history[0] = line;` is a viable solution (although not the best from a performance perspective)

Comment: Fixed @M.M [15 chars]

Comment: not a good fix as you need to call `malloc` only when you know the length of the line... you are making 10 buffers the same size

Comment: Personally, I'd just use `strdup`, which is just as posix-standard as `getline`. But it's worth explaining *why* you need to make the copy, because you only need to do so if you are reusing the original `line` buffer.